# All partitions missing when copying

Tags: windows, hardware, hard-drive

I bought a new 320GB SATA hard drive few months ago no recently when i try to copy something to the drive after about 20 seconds the all the partitions in the hard drive suddenly disappears.
The hard drive is not shown in either Disk manager or device manager. To get the HD work i have to restart the PC again.The same thing happens when i try to copy. Even when i play any audio or video after abt 5 minutes i get the same problem.
The drives are NTFS and im running Windows XP.. Xan some one please help me solve the problem??

Comment: belongs on SuperUser - not programming related

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the ide hard drive that i had connected, there seems to be a speed issue. Changing the ide to a different sata drive solved it

Answer (score 0):

did you check all the wires ? sounds like a disconnect of the wire somehow ... otherwise the hdd is broken...

Comment: All the wired are fixed perfect...I double checked the cables..It has been only 3 months :(

Comment: i cant imagine this to be a software problem if you dont have the same issues with other hdd's as well... hm did you try plugging it into another s-ata port on your mainboard ? and another power plug too, also it could be an issue with your power supply if it doesnt give you enough volt...